# Updating to Rails 3 on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

While trying to install Rails 3, I get the following error:

command run: `sudo gem install rails --pre`

error'd now with:

```
Successfully installed rails-3.0.0.rc2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.0.rc2...
File not found: lib
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or if you don't want to worry about running versions side by side you can do

```
gem update rails
```

At least it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 is out of beta/rc now, so try:

```
gem install rails --version 3.0.0
```

It should work on Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2-p0.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally seen that issue, but you could try and get around it by using the `--no-ri` option.

```
sudo gem install rails --pre --no-ri
```

There's also a `--no-rdoc` option if you have trouble with that too.